# Padding works on button, centering doesn't

Tags: css, button, center

[image: Button]

I have tried using `text-align: center;`, `justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center;` but this button's position will still stay the same.

If I try use padding however, like `padding: 750px` it works, and the button moves to the center.

This is my HTML code of that button:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="btn">
      <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And this is my [`button.css`](https://pastebin.com/BWaJEkMQ) file.

How do I center my button, please? Thank you!

Comment: How about `margin: auto` to `.btn`?

Comment: `span` is only using the space that matches the content, so centering the text has no effect, since it is centered in a container with the exact matching size. Using `margin: auto` like @SatoTakeru proposes should work

Comment: I tried doing `margin: auto;` on it just now, and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, @jkoestinger, I don't mean `margin: auto` to `span`, I mean to `.btn`.

Answer (score 0):

I made a test here with your CSS and the problem was the width, after I took out the text was in the center

```
            .container {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
        .btn {
  height: 100px;
  color: var(--white);
  font-family: "Zen Kaku Gothic New", sans-serif;
  font-size: 23px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 90px;
 
  transition: all 0.3s;
  position: relative;
}
```

[image]